# Typescript Arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am learning some Typescript and i am putting everthing i learn in a single page
I keep encountering this error called

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

but it still shows the array on the liveserver
[LiveServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oawu.png)

Will this affect the code or can i ignore?

this is my code

````
let description: string= `This TypeScript string can 
span multiple 
lines
`;

let firstName: string = "Testing";
let title: string = "This is a testing page"
let profile: string = `I'm ${firstName}. 
${title}`;

console.log(profile);

let testArray: string[];

testArray=['Typescript','Gaming','Javascript','Python'];
console.log(testingArray);

let heading = document.createElement('h1');
heading.textContent = message;
let body = document.createElement('h2');
body.textContent = description;
let Name = document.createElement('h5');
Name.textContent = profile;
let testingArray = document.createElement('h5');
testingArray.textContent = testArray;
document.body.appendChild(heading);
document.body.appendChild(body);
document.body.appendChild(Name);
document.body.appendChild(testingArray); ```
````

Comment: The `.textContent` of an element is a *string*, not an array of strings

Comment: according to sites like tutorialteacher, if i want to add this array to the site i have to modify the js file to include a ```var testingArray: Array<string>```. is that correct?

Comment: No, that will make no (positive) difference. Look at what you're assigning to the `.textContent` of the element. It's not a string.

Comment: Just properly make a string from your string array then assign the string to `textContent`. You can make use of the handy [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

Comment: just to confirm, whatever i modify in app.ts will show up in app.js and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `textContent` is a `string` and you are storing an array of strings. So
the error is right. You need to convert the array to string using methods like join.

```
testingArray.textContent = testArray.join();
```

Or create multiple textContent by looping over the array, anything according to your logic.

```
document.body.appendChild(heading);
document.body.appendChild(body);
document.body.appendChild(Name);
for(let testEle of testArray) {
    let testingArray = document.createElement('h5');
    testingArray.textContent = testEle;
    document.body.appendChild(testingArray);
}
```

> Will this affect the code or can i ignore?

Well I would say not to ignore, as ignoring didn't help me run it successfully in other live servers like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/).